# System is responding too slow after installing Nvidia drivers in Ubuntu12.10

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, wubi, flicker, amd-processor

My monitor was flickering after booting Ubuntu 12.10. The problem was increasing if I start moving my mouse and when it is kept idle, the flickering used to stop.

My system has an AMD 32 bit processor with a Nvidia graphics card. 
In Windows the monitor doesn't have any problem.

In-order to resolve this problem, I had installed Nvidia drivers by following the below steps.

1. `sudo apt-get install linux-source`
2. `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic`
3. `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`

Now the flickering issue is not there. But my system is too slow after logging into Ubuntu. It takes at least one minute even for opening a window. Please let me know how to solve this.

Comment: I have seen this problem with laptops having graphics card, but it was slightly different, in that it only flickered just before the log-in screen and stopped after the log in screen appeared. Is that your problem too??

Comment: For me, the flickering starts only after logging in and it doesn't stop but reduces to an extend if the mouse is kept idle. And if i start working(with flickering) for a few minutes, the system hangs. Before this i had tried installing Ubuntu 12.04, even that had problem. After installing Ubuntu 12.04 and once i logged in, the desktop appeared to be blank without any icons. When i read some similar problems in different forums, i got to know that Ubuntu 10 and above versions doesn't support the Nvidia graphics card. So please let me know what can be done to resolve the issue.

Comment: As per the instructions, i have installed Nvidia drivers and the flickering has stopped. But now the system is too slow after logging into Ubuntu 12.10. Windows is working normally. I have installed nvidia drivers, after removing the existing one. The following steps were executed after removing the existing Nvidia driver. 1.sudo apt-get install linux-source 2.sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic 3.sudo apt-get install nvidia-current